# Search in JavaScript object with wildcards?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of objects which I would like to contain wildcards.
Is it possible to somehow implement wildcards in my objects' keys and allow this type of matching?

```
dict = [{"foo*" : "A" }, {"bar*" : "B"}]

if (dict["foo_1_2"]){
    console.log("FOUND");
}
```

Comment: Please explain your use case in a lot more detail

Comment: Asterisks are not valid key identifiers in JavaScript. This will not work.

Comment: The proper way to accomplish this is by using a _look up_ collection (an Array of ids to look up).

Comment: I have a JSON "dict" which contains element IDs and certain rules / values.
Some rules values can apply to multiple IDs.
So in the example above I may have IDs = foo_1_2, foo_1_3, foo_2_2, bar_5_4.
I want to be able to match by wildcard and apply the rules / values stored in JSON for that element.

Comment: Well considering that there is no wildcard method... and you haven't really added much clarification you could make the `dict` an object instead of array or use `Array#find()` to look for what you need in an array

Comment: I don't understand how this question is too broad. I understood Federico's question very clearly. He wants a dictionary of keys that pertain as a regex parameter to search against. I have an answer, and someone answered this question that is correct as well. This makes no sense as to why this question has been put on hold after answers have been submitted. 

Here is my answer: 
`Array.prototype.objectKeyMatches = function(search) {return Object.entries(this).filter(([key,val])=>RegExp('^'+Object.keys(val)[0]).test(search)).length > 0;}; console.log(dict.objectKeyMatches('foo_1_2'));`

Answer (score 1):

one way you can do is iterate over array get key of each object and test with regx

```
var key="foo_1_2";
var dict = [{"foo*" : "A" }, {"bar*" : "B"}]

function isKeyExists(key,array){
  for(var i in array){
  var regX = new RegExp('^'+Object.keys(array[i]),"g");

    if(regX.test(key)){
      return true;
    }
  }

  return false;
}

console.log(isKeyExists(key,dict));
```